# Angular CDK/drag-drop allow underlying controll and scroll of element

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

Moving a img with cdk drag-drop works totally fine. But if the div I want to drag is scrollable, the cdk drag is prioritized, resulting in a non-scrollable div.

Important: MOBILE! - Scroll with PC (scroll wheel) is working.

```
<div #draggable
       cdkDrag
       (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnd($event)"
       (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoving($event)"
       [ngClass]="{'active': active, 'next': next}"
       class="nibbl-wrapper">
    <div class="nibbl-container"
         (click)="changeOverlay()">
      <img #image
           *ngIf="nibbl.type === 'png' || nibbl.type === 'jpeg' || nibbl.type === 'jpg'"
           alt="" crossOrigin="anonymous"
           id="{{nibbl.id}}"
           src="{{nibbl.links[0]}}"
      >
      <mat-video *ngIf="nibbl.type === 'mp4'"
                 #video
                 title="{{nibbl.title}}" [autoplay]="false" [preload]="true" [download]="false" spinner="spin"
                 [loop]="true"
                 src="{{nibbl.links[0]}}">
      </mat-video>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also the controlls of the video, e.g. volume, cant be changed with the slider, because the drag is kind of blocking it.

Is there a possibility to allow touch scrolling before triggering drag and drop?